# how to check the current status of server(up/down) from my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to check the current status of server(up/down) from my rails application . If server become down,and many users are logined, I need to perform some actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ping is really easy in ruby, maybe someone with some more rails experience can give more related info though.

```
require 'ping'

Ping.pingecho "www.google.com"
=> true
```

Ping can also take in a timeout default is 5 and a port.

Comment: `gem list ping -r` lists a lot of things *starting* with ping.  Can you tell us which gem you used?